# How to clear peer list?

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers, peer-discovery

How to clear bitcoind's peer list? (also containing peers in the past)

I didn't find an RPC command for it, is it stored in a file?
Where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop bitcoind, and delete the `peers.dat` file in the data directory. On next startup, bitcoind will start a new one, by seeding from DNS seeds and other means.

Why, though? Generally the peers database you have will be better quality than the new initial one you get.